# Can I install ubuntu 22.04 alongside my exiting ubuntu 20.04 in a separate partition?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, partitioning, 22.04

I am too scared to touch my current 20.04 setup (various reasons), but at the same time I want to test 22.04. Can I have both in two partitions and be able to choose freely while booting? This would solve a lot of my issues!

Comment: Generally, no problem, but if you had made a /home partition, you should not use that same one on a different OS, the system program configuration files (dot files) will be different, and may cause problems.  A separate partition for your data would be fine.

Comment: If your computer is powerful enough (enough RAM, CPU threads) you may consider running Ubuntu 22.04 in a [virtual machine using QEMU/KVM](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-qemu-kvm-on-ubuntu-22-04-20-04-lts/). This is what I do for non-LTS versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Anecdotally I have a desktop that started out as Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It has been upgraded three times (LTS to LTS) and now runs 22.04. So fare so good! If I still have this hardware next year, when Ubuntu 24.04.1 comes out, I may do a clean install and restore my data from backup, just to get rid of all the unused applications accumulated over the years.

Comment: If you want to test 22.04, why not try it in a live usb session? As the answer below shows, you can do what you’re asking, but you might end up with a slightly ‘messy’ system - 2 home partitions, potentially different versions of the same data etc. Personally, I’d check it works in a live usb session, backup all your data carefully, then (assuming it was ok in live session) install 22.04 - you can always go back to 20.04 if it doesn’t work out - installing Ubuntu is so quick it’s not a disaster if it doesn’t work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sure you can install multiple linux versions on a same computer in separate partitions and then select one at boot time. If needed, you must reduce the current system partition to make free space for the new installation.

Whatever you do, make sure you have an up-to-date backup of your current user data. Once you have that, disaster cannot anymore strike. An operating system is reinstalled in 30 minutes. Your data, however, once lost, is lost forever.